# XGBoost (Extreme Gradient Boosting) or Elastic Net More Robust to Outliers

Tags: predictive-models, outliers, cart, boosting, glmnet

I have recently been doing work with predictive models for a continuous response. I am doing a comparison between Elastic Net (`glmnet`) package in R and XGBoost (`xgboost`) package in R. Originally, I built the model using Elastic Net for its ability to perform feature selection and also for its ability to shrink the coefficeints of correlated variables.

I am exploring XGBoost because of its predictive capabilities, the summary of feature importance it provides, its ability to capture non-linear interactions and also because I believe that it might be more robust in the presence of outliers.

My questions are:

1. Is XGBoost or gradient boosted trees in general better at finding non-linear interactions than a generalized linear model?
2. Is my assumption about XGBoost or gradient boosted trees in general being robust to outliers a fair assumption?

Here is my model set up and finding:

For model validation I have a training and testing set. I $log$ transform the response variables before model fitting. I make predictions on the testing set and then exponentiate the results to return to the original scale. I make predicted vs. observed plots for each model.

**XGBoost Predicted Vs. Observed Plot**
[image]

The exponentiated predicted values have some outliers but the fit in general is good.

**Elastic Net Predicted Vs. Observed Plot**
[image]

With the elastic net model when I convert back to original scale there is an extreme predicted value. I am interpreting this as that the GLM NET has a few cases that it is not quite sure how to predict (outliers).

I would love to hear opinions! Thank you in advance for any help or comments!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- 1 Yes boosted trees would more easily fit unknown non-linear effects or interactions than regularized linear regression. However, as soon as you are aware of some specific non-linearity you could simply transform data to linearity and continue to use a linaer learner.
- 2 That depends on how you train the models. If you're new to boosted trees, check out some tutorials on how to avoid overfitting. I cannot see from your plots what kind of cross-validation was used. Use a thorough outer cross-validation and perhaps compare the results to a random forest model. RF models are much easier to handle, and default settings are often near optimal. A crude thumb rule; if your RF performs better than boosted trees(measured by outer cross validation), you either have chosen sub optimal training paramters for your boosted trees model or your data is quite noisy.